# Tables not displaying after creating database by script. Do I need to insert?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I successfully created (scripted) a database in SQL Server 2012.

My problem is that while the database itself is listed in the object explorer, the tables from the database are not. The database I scripted did not contain actual data, i.e., there were no 'Insert' statements. Is this last the reason why the tables are not listed?

I tried to see if the tables were stored somehow without appearing by running an insert into statement for  one of the tables in the script statement , but I get an error:

> " Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid object name
>   'ContactInfo'. "

What am I doing wrong? Why aren't the database tables listed?

Here is the actual script I used:

```
CREATE DATABASE [Name]; 
GO

CREATE TABLE Company  (CompName Varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY , CompCity VarChar(20), CompState CHAR(2), CompAddress Varchar(50), CompZip SMALLINT  );

CREATE TABLE NamePhone (CompName VarChar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Company(CompName) , CompPhone   Varchar (12) NOT NULL );

CREATE TABLE ContactInfo (ContactFName NVarChar(20) PRIMARY KEY , ContactLName NVarchar(20), ContTitle Varchar(10), ContactDirPhone Char(10), ContEmail Varchar(320)
, ContCompany Varchar(10) REFERENCES Company(CompName) );

CREATE TABLE ContactReportsTo (ReportstoFName NVarChar(20) , ReportstoLName NVarchar(30), ReportstoPhone Varchar(50), ReportstoCompany Varchar(10) REFERENCES
Company(CompName),  ContactFName NVarchar(20)  REFERENCES ContactInfo(ContactFName));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Object Explorer, drill down to your database, and then to Tables.

Right-click Tables and click Refresh.

If your newly created tables do not show up, perhaps you created the tables under a different database by mistake. This might happen if you were missing a `USE YourDatabase` in which case they would likely end up in the default database for your login (often `master`)

Also, the following will show all of the tables in a database. Run it for your database. If they do not show up, SQL Server did not create the tables (at all/in the desired location).

```
use [YOUR_DATABASE] 
GO 
select * from sys.tables 
GO
```